# holomorphic in a neighborhood of the closure of the unit disk, and an equality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in a neighborhood of the closure of the unit disk $D$.

Show that $\forall |z|\le 1$

$f(z)(1-|z|^2)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{|u|=1} \frac{1-\overline{z}u}{u-z}f(u)du$.

This is what I tried to do, but I'm a little confused. Well.. Since the curve $|u|=1$ is contained in the domain of the analytic function , we can use Cauchy integral formula. Using Cauchy integral formula, and then multiplying by $(1-|z|^2)$ to both sides, we get the following equality:$$
f\left( z \right)\left( {1 - |z|^2 } \right) = \frac{1}
{{2\pi i}}\int\limits_{|u| = 1} {\frac{{f\left( u \right)}}
{{u - z}}\left( {1 - |z|^2 } \right)du} 
$$ So it's remain to show that: $$
\int\limits_{|u| = 1} {\frac{{f\left( u \right)}}
{{u - z}}\left( {1 - |z|^2 } \right)du}  = \int\limits_{|u| = 1} {\frac{{f\left( u \right)}}
{{u - z}}\left( {1 - \overline z u} \right)du} 
$$
Or equivalently:
$$
0 = \int\limits_{|u| = 1} {\frac{{f\left( u \right)}}
{{u - z}}\left( {\overline z u - |z|^2 } \right)du}  = \int\limits_{|u| = 1} {\frac{{f\left( u \right)}}
{{u - z}}\overline z \left( {u - z} \right)du = } \int\limits_{|u| = 1} {f\left( u \right)\overline z du = } \overline z \int\limits_{|u| = 1} {f\left( u \right)du} 
$$

But something has to be wrong here

Comment: $f$ is homomorphic, so your final integral is zero by Cauchy's Theorem!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but me thinks you already have it: $$\oint_{|u|=1}f(u)\,du=0$$ since $\,f\,$ is analytic on and within the unit circle!

Comment: Oh you are completely right! Thanks